# How do I append to the unnamed register?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register, global-command

In particular, I'd like to append to the unnamed register with the `:global` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no shortcut to append *only* to the default register (the way you can append to a letter register by using the uppercase register name.)

In order to append only to the default register, you'd have to use a full `let @" .= ...` expression, such as:

```
:g/pattern/let @" .= getline('.')."\n"
```

But that's quite unsatisfying. It's much better to use a letter register instead, and then use the uppercase version of the register to append to it.

Writing to a letter register will *also* write to the unnamed register (thanks @Mass for pointing that out!). From [`:help quote_quote`]:

> Vim fills this register with text deleted with the `d`, `c`, `s`, `x` commands or copied with the yank `y` command, regardless of whether or not a specific register was used (e.g. `"xdd`). This is like the **unnamed register is pointing to the last used register.  Thus when appending using an uppercase register name, the unnamed register contains the same text as the named register.**

So we can just use a named register as a "proxy" to the unnamed register. We can initialize it with the initial contents of the unnamed register, then append to it, which will get the unnamed register to include the appends:

```
:call setreg('x', @", getregtype('"'))
:g/pattern/y X
```

While you'll be primarily appending to register `"x`, the unnamed register will *also* get the same contents, mirroring the named register you last appended to.

Comment: Maybe not the spirit of the question but, :g/^/y A does "append to the unnamed" register after the first line

Comment: @Mass It actually does... Why is it that this works and *appends* these lines to the default register other than the `"a` register?

Comment: Well, the trick is that when you perform any yank (except to _), the unnamed register is updated to point to that register (your answer is totally correct).

Comment: @filbranden I'll accept for now, but this solution does not work for Neovim

Comment: @Jay Interesting... I don't see how NeoVim could behave differently in this are, did you dig down to see where it fails? In any case, I think using a letter register and the uppercase version to append is the right approach...

Comment: Thanks @Mass ! Yeah I can see that's even mentioned on the documentation. TIL! Updated my answer to reflect this fact.

Comment: Is is possible that the `write` only happen once? The unnamed  register might  just be pointer, if you do `"x{some_operation}`, and then `let @x="blah"`, then `p`, you get `blah`.

Comment: @dedowsdi Yeah good point! It's exactly a pointer!!!

Comment: @Mass I get `blah` when I do that sequence... I'm on Vim 8.2.717. Doesn't look like I have any mappings that would affect this.

Comment: @Mass Are you sure ? That's the same as my example, I just tried it again, `blah` is always put.

Comment: @dedowsdi, sorry, not sure what was or I imagined happening, but I can't reproduce any more with --clean.